# Best algorthm to get all combination pair of nodes in an undirected graph (need to improve time complexity)

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, graph, graph-algorithm

I have an undirected graph A that has : no multiple-links between any two nodes , no self-connected node, there can be some isolated nodes (nodes with degree 0).

I need to go through all the possible combinations of pair of nodes in graph A to assign some kind of score for non-existence links (Let say if my graph has k nodes and n links, then the number of combination should be (k*(k-1)/2 - n) of combinations). The way that I assign score is based on the common neighbor nodes between the 2 nodes of combination.

[image: Ex: score between A-D should be 1, score between G-D should be 0 ...]
Ex: score between A-D should be 1, score between G-D should be 0 ...

The biggest problem is that my graph has more than 100.000 nodes and it was too slow to handle almost 10^10 combinations which is my first attempt to approach the solution.

My second thought is since the algorithm is based on common neighbors of the node, I might only need to look at the neighbors so that I can assign score which is different from 0. The rest can be determined as 0 and no need to compute. But this could possibly repeat a combination.

Any idea to approach this solution is appreciated. Please keep in mind that the actual network has more than 100.000 nodes.

Comment: have you tried anything before coming here? please share your code

Comment: You should try asking this on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ as well, as the question isn't exactly about programming (or Java), but rather about a theoretical approach.

Comment: Is there any bound on  number of edges ?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your scoring system. Are you saying you're trying to find, for two nodes, the number of paths of length two between those nodes?

Comment: @No Idea For Name : yes I did try but the code is too long , I can get the algorithm part for you here http://pastebin.com/KW8Xg0H4

Comment: @beaker : it's not about path of length the score between A and D is 1 because they have 1 common neighbor which is B. similarly for the rest ....

Comment: Okay, two nodes having one common neighbor means that there is a path of length two between those nodes. The reason I ask is that you don't give any examples of scores other than zero or one, but if this is what you want then the number of solutions is O(k^2) so in general you're not going to get better time complexity than you state above. That is unless you have more information about the structure of the graph that would allow you to rule out certain sets of solutions.

Comment: @Spandan: actually the number of edge is around 600.000 but it doesn't matter , right ?

Comment: Actually, it matters a great deal that your graph is so sparse. Hopefully @Spandan will come along and expand on the idea, but this makes your "second thought" above much faster.

Comment: @Nexus: Is it an online judge problem ? Can you post a link ? I need to know , the constraint between , number of nodes and edges,for a particular graph .And since you say , you cant process 10^10 pairs, you'll anyway will have to process the pairs when you output them.
Correct me if i am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you represent your graph as an adjacency list (rather than an adjacency matrix), you can make use of the fact that your graph has only 600,000 edges to hopefully reduce the computation time.

Let's take a node `V[j]` with neighbors `V[i]` and `V[k]`:

```
V[i] ---- V[j] ---- V[k]
```

To find all such pairs of neighbors you can take the list of nodes adjacent to `V[j]` and find all combinations of those nodes. To avoid duplicates you will have to generate the combinations rather than the permutations of the end nodes `V[i]` and `V[k]` by requiring that `i < k`.

Alternatively, you can start with node `V[i]` and find all of the nodes that have a distance of 2 from `V[i]`. Let `S` be the set of all the nodes adjacent to `V[i]`. For each node `V[j]` in `S`, create a path `V[i]-V[j]-V[k]` where:

1. `V[k]` is adjacent to `V[j]`
2. `V[k]` is not an element of `S` (to avoid directly connected nodes)
3. `k != i` (to avoid cycles)
4. `k > i` (to avoid duplications)

I personally like this approach better because it completes the adjacency list for one node before moving on to the next.

Given that you have ~600,000 edges in a graph with ~100,000 nodes, assuming an even distribution of edges across all of the nodes each node would have an average degree of 12. The number of possible paths for each node is then on the order of 10<sup>2</sup>. Over 10<sup>5</sup> nodes that gives on the order of 10<sup>7</sup> total paths rather than the theoretical limit of 10<sup>10</sup> for a complete graph. Still a large number, but a thousand times faster than before.